# sd card recovery with full data including hd videos, pictures, songs

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card

My sandisk 16GB was full with many HD videos, songs,pictures .I insert the SD card in Samsung Galaxy Core 2.But one day in the notification panel I saw SD card damaged .So I insert the SD card in Accer tablet.It inserted properly but the data in the SD card blanked.How I recover my all  data in the SD card?

Comment: Downvoted because "question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is valuable you send it to a recovery expert.

If you are willing to risk it, you treat it like you would a damaged hard drive.  (Search data recovery on this site - there are plenty of answers).

Most answers boil down to something like -

1. Get a Linux distro with DDRescue on it.
2. Make a bitcopy of the SD Card.
3. Attempt recovery on the bitcopy of the sdcard.  You might want to make a copy of the copy, and act on that.

   a.  Photorec and testdisk are often used to recover data.  Photorec will probably not be able to recover all the data.